# C# How to edit different Strings and give output in textbox

Tags: c#

I am working on a GUI for work with my NFC cards.

Now I have a functionality in the device I use to switch in reader mode and identify the card type, read uid, ATQA, SAK and give it back as a `String`.

My idea was the following:

```
var identify = SendCommand($"IDENTIFY").ToString();
txt_identify.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}";
txt_identify.Text += ($"--Card Identification--{Environment.NewLine}{identify}{Environment.NewLine}");
```

`identify` with the `SendCommand` give for example these `String`s back in the `TextBox`:

> --Card Identification--
>   MIFARE UltralightATQA: 4400UID: 0466F5BADA5180SAK: 00
>   --Card Identification--
>   MIFARE Classic 1kATQA: 0400UID: FDE99349SAK: 08

The results should be a bit more readable:

> --Card Identification--
>   MIFARE Ultralight
>   ATQA: 4400
>   UID: 0466F5BADA5180
>   SAK: 00
>   --Card Identification--
>   MIFARE Classic 1k
>   ATQA: 0400
>   UID: FDE99349
>   SAK: 08

But I have no idea how to get this done. Doesn't find a way with split or regex.
Maybe someone of you have an idea?

Comment: The question is, whether there is an invisible separator that the TextBox does not display. Identify it and replace it by `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ATQA:`, `UID:` and `SAK:` are values you get every time, you can use replace:

```
var identify = SendCommand($"IDENTIFY").ToString();

txt_identify.Text += "\r\n--Card Identification--\r\n" + identify
                     .Replace("ATQA:", "\r\nATQA:\t")
                     .Replace("UID:", "\r\nUID:\t")
                     .Replace("SAK:", "\r\nSAK:\t");
```

Comment: Thanks that work for me. Need to add \r\n like commented from Alessio Cantarella

Comment: Glad to help :-) Changed `\n` to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a method that formats the returned data string:

```
static string FormatIdentitfyOutput(string v)
{
    // keywords to be put on new line
    var words = new[] { "ATQA:", "UID:", "SAK:" };

    foreach (var w in words)
        v = v.Replace(w, Environment.NewLine + w);

    return $"--Card Identification--{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{v}";
}
```

Test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string f = FormatIdentitfyOutput("MIFARE UltralightATQA:  4400UID:    0466F5BADA5180SAK:  00");

    Console.WriteLine(f);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
--Card Identification--

MIFARE Ultralight
ATQA:  4400
UID:    0466F5BADA5180
SAK:  00
```

Comment: Same idea as @ZoharPeled - he was faster